# Change boolean value to True for duplicates with more distant/far date pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given dataframe I want to set `isActive` column value to `True` only duplicated value and add '_duplicate' to the `Name` column.

```
df = 

Name    isActive    LoginDate

John    False       2021      
John    False       2022 
Fred    False       2020
```

Desired output is:

df =

```
Name              isActive    LoginDate

John_duplicate    True        2021      
John              False       2022 
Fred              False       2020
```

For now I was able to add numbers to each duplicates, but I want to skip with nearest login date and add text to oldest. And change boolean value:

```
df.LoginDate = ad.groupby('LoginDate').LoginDate.apply(lambda n: n + (np.arange(len(n))+1).astype(str))
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for first value per `Name` with chaining `duplicated` with `keep=False` for first duplicated `Name` and set column `isActive` with append substring to `Name`:

```
m = ~df['Name'].duplicated() & df['Name'].duplicated(keep=False)
df['isActive'] = m
df.loc[m, 'Name'] +=  '_duplicate'

print (df)
             Name  isActive  LoginDate
0  John_duplicate      True       2021
1            John     False       2022
2            Fred     False       2020
```

Comment: Sorry sorry. My Bad. I want users with 2021 date to be with text '_duplicate' and True

Comment: @Mamed - Can you test now?